# set of predicate sentences infinite or finite?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

A set T has the functions of every predicate for a particular domain. Is a domain of all possible predicates for a domain a finite number because there can't be infinite predicate sentences. I was wondering because if its infinite is it countable or uncountable.

**e.g.**

Consider the set of predicate logic sentences we can write about the
“Possible Missions” domain.
Is this set finite; infinite but countable; or not countable? Explain your
answer.

My assumption is its finite since there shouldn't be infinite possible missions.

Thanks.

Comment: A *predicate* $S(x)$  is a symbol of the Language; it has meaning when interpreted in a domain $D$. The domain may be either finite or infinite : if the domain $D$ is the collection of **all** living creatures, the predicate "$x$ is a student" will be interpreted with a subset of $D$, i.e. with the subset of the collection of all living creatures that are students. Obviously, the set of students is finite.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit it and make it more clear to the question i was doing

Comment: In first order language, provided we have at least one predicate symbol $Px$, the number of formulas is infinite countable : $Px, \lnot Px, \lnot \lnot Px, \ldots$ and every possible combination of the atomic formula with the propositional connectives.

Comment: Didn't see it like that. Thanks so much for helping!